# Animation shows View after animation when setting View.GONE

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to animate a button to fade away, and then set its visibility to VIEW.GONE in order for it to not take up space on the page.
The code is as follows

```
 myContinueButton.animate().setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            myContinueButton.setEnabled(false);
            myContinueButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
 }).alpha(0f);
```

The issue is that the button will fade away, but then it will briefly appear in full when the visibility is set in side the onAnimationEnd.
Ive tried setting alpha before the listener, but the result is always the same:
Object fades away, then appears again on screen, then hides as it is set to View.Gone

Comment: can you show me complete animation code you used and may be xml used for animation

Comment: There could be other places in your Code that sets its Visibility and/or Alpha just after the View.GONE is executed. Try to use "myContinueButton.post(newRunnable(){ myContinueButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); });"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
 myContinueButton.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(500).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            myContinueButton.setAlpha(0f);
            myContinueButton.setEnabled(false);
            myContinueButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    }).start();
```